# Selection automatically put into X11 clipboard - VIM

Tags: vim

In my previous Linux install, when I selected some text in visual mode (without the mouse!), it would automatically put it in my X11 clipboard. Then I could naturally paste this text anywhere else using the mouse middle button.

With my new Linux installation, this doesn't work anymore (merely selecting text in visual mode doesn't put it in X11 clipboard anymore).

How can I get this nice feature back?

(I am not interested into the `"*y` or `"+y` solutions, which by the way don't work on my system.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the 3K+ followers of the vim tag? And if the answer seems so simple to you why not write it down?

Comment: @Max But then what is Stackoverflow a manual for?

Comment: if `"+y` and `"*y` don't work in your system, you should check whether you could get a Vim version that is compiled with good features for interacting with X11.

Comment: `vim --version | grep xterm_clipboard` returns `+wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard`

Comment: @subshit: `-xterm_clipboard` means: feature not activated.

Answer (score 8):

The visual selection (v, V, or CTRL-V) can automatically be copied to the
X11 selection (* buffer).

In non-gui mode the clipboard option controls this (only supported if
+xterm_clipboard appears when you type vim --version).  In gui mode
guioptions controls it.

This makes all Visual mode selections automatically go to the X11 primary
selection:

```
set clipboard+=autoselect
set guioptions+=a
```

This turns it off:

```
set clipboard-=autoselect
set guioptions-=a
```

In vim see:

```
help 'clipboard'
```

(single quotes required)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
set guioptions+=a
```

This works with the GUI (Gvim). Reference is at `:help guioptions_a`.

```
                        *guioptions_a* *'go-a'*
  'a'   Autoselect:  If present, then whenever VISUAL mode is started,
    or the Visual area extended, Vim tries to become the owner of
    the windowing system's global selection.  This means that the
    Visually highlighted text is available for pasting into other
    applications as well as into Vim itself.  When the Visual mode
    ends, possibly due to an operation on the text, or when an
    application wants to paste the selection, the highlighted text
    is automatically yanked into the "* selection register.
    Thus the selection is still available for pasting into other
    applications after the VISUAL mode has ended.
        If not present, then Vim won't become the owner of the
    windowing system's global selection unless explicitly told to
    by a yank or delete operation for the "* register.
    The same applies to the modeless selection.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm afraid the problem comes from my system, but I don't understand where because my version of vim seems to be compiled with the needed features, as I mentioned in a comment in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

When using Vim inside gnome-terminal on Arch and Gentoo Linux this functionality just works.

When using Vim inside Konsole this does not work.

Using `gvim -v` will launch a terminal version of GVim where `set guioptions+=a` **works**:
  any text selected within that Vim is automatically copied to Linux's selection buffer.

To paste text from the selection buffer press the middle mouse button

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian I got it working after installing vim-gnome package.

A comment from pkg-vim-maintainers mailing list instructs to install either vim-gtk, vim-gnome or vim-lesstif.

Answer (score 0):

With my new installation of Kali, I solved the issue above by installing vim-gtk package for gnome-terminal. The vim-gtk package changes the "-xterm_clipboard" to "+xterm_clipboard", and the problem is solved. After selecting text in vim, the text will be copied to system clipboard automatically.